# How to add a result column into my table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing data cleaning practice in SSMS. I made a mock postcode table which needs to be cleaned:

[image]

Then I used SUBSTRING to grab the first half and second half:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_code,1,3)
FROM PostCode;

SELECT SUBSTRING(post_code, LEN(post_code)-2,LEN(post_code))
FROM PostCode
```

[image]

For the next step, I am trying to add the 2 columns into my table then I can combine them together.  How should I do that?

Thank you very much for and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post_code,1,3) + SUBSTRING(post_code, LEN(post_code)-2,LEN(post_code))
FROM PostCode;
```

if this gives you the right results then update:

```
update PostCode 
set post_code = SUBSTRING(post_code,1,3) + SUBSTRING(post_code, LEN(post_code)-2,LEN(post_code))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(post_code,1,3) AS first,
    SUBSTRING(post_code, LEN(post_code)-2,LEN(post_code)) AS second
FROM PostCode;
```

I see that your postal code may or may not have extra stray characters such as space or comma.  You may try removing them before you apply string operations:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(post_code, ' ', ''), ',', '') AS post_code
    FROM PostCode
)

SELECT
    SUBSTRING(post_code,1,3) AS first,
    SUBSTRING(post_code, LEN(post_code)-2,LEN(post_code)) AS second
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Not really. I am trying to combine them together into a column, then add it to my table replace the original post_code column.

Comment: Your code indicates that you want to create two new columns.  Please show us your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` to extract the components:

```
SELECT LEFT(post_code, 3) as firsthalf,
       RIGHT(post_code, 3) as secondhalf
FROM PostCode;
```

This will not work if `post_code` is stored as a `char(7)` rather than a `varchar(<something>)`.  In that case, use:

```
SELECT LEFT(post_code, 3) as firsthalf,
       SUBSTR(post_code, LEN(post_code) - 2, 3) as secondhalf
FROM PostCode;
```

For the rest of this answer, you can replace `RIGHT(post_code, 3)` with the above expression, if you need that.

Using `LEN(post_code)` for the length argument for `secondhalf` is allowed, but misleading, because you know it is 3 characters.

I'm not sure what you mean by:

> I am trying to add the 2 columns into my table then I can combine them together

But SQL Server supports computed columns:

```
alter table PostCode add firsthalf as (LEFT(post_code, 3));
alter table PostCode add secondhalf as (RIGHT(post_code, 3));
```

`firsthalf` and `secondhalf` will then appear as columns in the table, just like any other columns (except you cannot explicit alter or set their values because they are computed from `post_code`).

You can create a "clean Postal code" with similar logic:

```
alter table PostCode add cleanedPostCode as (LEFT(post_code, 3) + ' ' + RIGHT(post_code, 3));
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! When I used you code, I get this: 1H3
1H3
H3 
H3 
H3. First 2 result has extra space in the begin, last 3 only return 2 characters.

Comment: @Alle . . . That would not make sense, unless there is another character after the "3".  However, if you think that your logic works better than `RIGHT(post_code, 3)`, you can definitely use it instead.

Comment: @Alle . . . The mystery is solved.  You are storing `post_code` as `char(7)` -- not the type I would have used.  In any case, I've adapted the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Followed your solution, I got a clean postcode in my result. Then I am trying to add this new result into my table. I tried query like: alter table PostCode add new_postcode as (SELECT firsthalf + ' ' + secondhalf
  from PostCode). But it doesn't allow me to do so. So how should I do?

Comment: @Alle . . . An `update` is very dangerous.  If the codes are not what you expect, you will lose the original value and not be able to reconstruct it.  That is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057265/how-to-add-a-result-column-into-my-table/54057329#comment94948603_54057284)

> I am trying to combine them together into a column, then add it to my table replace the original post_code column.

Simply, you can do as

```
UPDATE PostCode
SET Post_Code = LEFT(Post_Code, 3) + RIGHT(Post_Code, 3);
```

Or if you have whitespaces in the begening/end of the string

```
UPDATE PostCode
SET Post_Code = LEFT(TRIM(Post_Code), 3) + RIGHT(TRIM(Post_Code), 3);
```

Note that **[`TRIM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** is only available on 2017 version, if you don't have it, you can use **[`LTRIM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`RTRIM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions as

```
UPDATE PostCode
SET Post_Code = LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Post_Code)), 3) + RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Post_Code)), 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your messing with dirty data, if you have a lot of rows you may want to follow up with some validation.

You can build a validation column, something like:

```
case when
    len(postcodeClean) = 6
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 1, 1)) = 0
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 2, 1)) = 1
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 3, 1)) = 0
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 4, 1)) = 1
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 5, 1)) = 0
    and isnumeric(SUBSTRING(postcodeClean, 6, 1)) = 1
then
    'valid'
else
    'not valid'
end [isItValid]
```

And/Or - depending on how dirty your data is, you may want to compare it to all valid Canada postal codes.

You can download them from

https://fusiontables.google.com/data?docid=1H_cl-oyeG4FDwqJUTeI_aGKmmkJdPDzRNccp96M#rows:id=1

Import them, and then compare your final result set to make sure they're all good.

Comment: Tip: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/). You may want to consider using `like` with a pattern, e.g. `PostCode like '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]'`. That will identify a "clean" post code, but not assist with cleaning an invalid one.